# IBM Watson Q and A API gives 500 response code

Tags: java, http, ibm-watson

I have written a Java Code to test the Watson Question and Answers API. However, I'm getting response code 500, when I run it. I have checked the api url and my login credentials. The problem seems to be somewhere  else. Any hints or debugging suggestions would be of great help.

```
    String url = "https://watson-wdc01.ihost.com/instance/526/deepqa/v1/question";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    //add reuqest header
    String userCredentials = "username:password";
    String basicAuth = "Basic " + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userCredentials.getBytes());
    con.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
    con.setRequestProperty("X-SyncTimeout", "30");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    con.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");

    String query = "{\"question\": {\"questionText\": \"" + "What are the common respiratory diseases?" + "\"}}";
    System.out.println(query);

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(query);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());
```

When i open the same url with the browser I get this:
    Watson Error!!
    Error Encountered!!
    Unable to communicate with Watson.
Whats wrong? Could it be something with the configuration? Or is the server down?

Answer (score 2):

> Any hints or debugging suggestions would be of great help.

1. Attempt the same request using your web browser ... or the `curl` utility.
2. Capture and output the contents of the error stream.

---

I don't think that this is the cause of your problems, but it is wrong anyway:

```
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(query);
wr.flush();
```

You are writing to an API that expects text (JSON).  You should therefore use a `Writer`, not a data (binary) output stream:

```
Writer wr = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream(), "LATIN-1");
wr.write(query);
wr.flush();
```